# Use DataBinding from Fragment to access views in its Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am using a fragment within an activity and using data binding to bind its layout for both the activity and fragment as shown below:

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@id/FAB_fromHomeActivity_BottomAppBarAttached"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_dark"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/BottomAppBar_fromHomeActivity_Main"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

activity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity)

}
```

fragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_goals, container, false)

        return mBinding.root
    }
```

Is there any way to access the FAB in the activity using the binding in the fragment ? (For example something like that mBinding.parent.FAB)

I can't find any information on this. Can anyone help ?

Comment: NO DataBinding does not care about the relationship b/w components . SO you have to get it in conventional way .. Get the Activity's reference and then get the `View`.